# I would like to simulate a media keypress in JQuery

Tags: jquery, eventtrigger

I'm currently trying to create a dartscounter as a website.

Currently a youtube video opens automatically, when someone has won. I also want Spotify to stop playing music.

How can I simulate a media keypress (f10 on my Keyboard -> keyCode 179)?

I've done lots of research and couldn't find anything but this solution

```
var press = jQuery.Event("keypress");
press.ctrlKey = false;
press.which = 179;
press.keyCode = 179;
$("document").trigger(press);
```

But spotify won't stop playing music with this code.

Do you guys have any idea??

Answer (score 0):

`"document"` -- this selector is not right.

You need to use `document` instead. `"document"` looks for an element such as `<document> ... </document>`, on the other hand, `document` is the actual HTML document you're firing the event on.

See the demo below:

```js
$(document).keypress((e) => {
  console.log(`Key pressed: Ctrl: ${e.ctrlKey}, Which: ${e.which}, Code: ${e.keyCode}`);
});

var press = jQuery.Event("keypress");
press.ctrlKey = false;
press.which = 179;
press.keyCode = 179;
$(document).trigger(press);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick replay, but the music still does not stop playing

Comment: @Dan_Paul_25 -- It will stop when you fire this event on the button which stops the playback. Instead of `$(document).trigger(press);`, you need to trigger this event on your own element.

Comment: I'm not quite sure, what you mean with my "own element". I want to simulate the "MediaPausPlay" keypress, which tells spotify to stop playing music. Do I need a special element on my website? Or where shall I trigger this event on?